# Is it possible to address a TFS 2015 Kanban board filter by URL?

Tags: tfs-2015

Recent versions of TFS 2015 allow you to filter the cards shown on a Kanban board by using a text filter (see "[Filter Kanban Board](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/kanban/filter-kanban-board#text-filter)" on MSDN).  Is it possible to save the filter criteria in the URL so that I could bookmark a filtered view of the board (e.g. to only show cards assigned to me)?

I was hoping that this would be possible since the URL supports adding `#fullScreen=true` to maximize the size of the board.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's impossible for now. Moreover, 'show cards assigned to me' this feature belongs to ***Filter by select field values***. This is only work with VSTS not with TFS2015.

[image]

If you need this feature, you can add a feature request and vote up it in [User Voice Site](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services). PM will kindly review it.